# Finite union of cylinder set again a cylinder set?

Tags: general-topology

$X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ with product topology $\tau$, where $S=\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ is equipped with the discrete topology. A base of $\tau$ is given by the cylinder sets
$$
C_t[a_0,...,a_m]:=\left\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in X: x_t=a_0,x_{t+1}=a_1,...,x_{t+m}=a_m\right\},
$$
where $a_i\in S, 0\leq i\leq m$.

I have a rather short question: Are finite unions of cylinder sets again cylinder sets? I think that is not the case. I think that for example
$$
C_0[1,1,2]\cup C_5[2,2,2]
$$
is no cylinder set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your example is not a cylinder set, since it says only *either* $x_0,x_1,x_2$ have the given values, *or* $x_5,x_6,x_7$ have the given values. So no specific subscript has been assigned a definite value, and so not a cylinder set.

Comment: What's with finite unions of disjoint cylinder sets, f.e. $C_0[1,2,1]\cup C_0[2,0,2]$?

Comment: @Rhjg I was reading too quickly and didn't notice it said "union". I've fixed that, still comes out not a cylinder set for a different reason.